# SQL Server Not Returning Results With Specific Words in Parameterised Query

Tags: sql-server, parameterized-query

I'm using a Parameterised Query to search for a particular word picked up from a search box but certain words are creating a problem. One of these is the word "pad".

It's a recipe database I'm using and there is a recipe called "pad Thai" in it; if I pass the word "thai" into the query parameter, that recipe is returned fine. If I pass the word "pad" in, the query runs for about 10 seconds and returns no records.

I was suspicious of "pad" being a reserved keyword so I've been trying other keywords; the only one I've found causing the same problem so far is "proc".

Any ideas what the problem is and, more importantly, how I can get around it.

Comment: Pad isn't a keyword that I know of. You'd be better to post the actual code used (and some example data) at let us take a look.

Comment: A key purpose of a parameterized query is to clearly separate the values from the language.  It should not at all be influenced by the use of reserved words.

Comment: What is your 'where' clause?  Are you using 'like', free text, or some other method?  Please post some code...

Comment: post the exact code you use and the database definition table, including all indexes.

Comment: Is it possible that there are international characters at play here?  What happens if you run the query not through your application but "closer" to the database (i.e. through SSMS)?

Comment: Jon - PAD is a reserved ODBC keyword as listed on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: phatfingers, I agree - that's why I'm so puzzled.

Comment: It's a complex query handling a lot of parameters but here goes if you can make sense of it:

Comment: Sorry, my code won't paste for some reason. It's late here (Ireland), I'll have a go in the morning again.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide much detail on HOW the code works I'm going to do some wild guessing that with 'parameterized query' you mean a stored procedure and that you call the stored procedure by means of it's entire text (not a best practice, but I don't know what the restrictions are of the software you're using).

Anyway, the reason `pad` or `proc` might cause problems is because you don't explicitly tell the server that these are strings. For reasons I've never truly understood, TSQL will allow you to pass single-word strings to (n)varchar parameters of procedures. A simple example would be :

```
EXEC sp_helpdb master
```

Strictly speaking this should give a syntax error. The correct syntax is :

```
EXEC sp_helpdb 'master'
```

But it seems the devs went with 'Hey it's less typing, that's great for productivity!' and so the query works.

Now if your procedure is called like this :

```
EXEC p_find_recipe thai
```

This will pass the string 'thai' and everything will run as expected. However, when using a reserved word like `proc` or `file` or `table` etc... that would cause a syntax error and you'd need to make sure to put quotes around the value for it to work.

All that said : 
 - the syntax error should be returned right away, it shouldn't take 10 seconds
 - AFAIK 'pad' is not a reseverd keyword

So I'm not sure supra applies to your problem and so it's quite possible I just spent 10 minutes typing for nothing =)

Anyway, you'll probably need to give some extra input on what language you're using, what you mean with parametrized query (maybe you mean the `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?` syntax where the ?'s are filled in afterwards ?), preferably with some example code.